# NGINX redirect to ssl

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect all requests to https, including subdomains. So i do:

```
server_name subdomain.example.com www.subdomain.example.com example.com www.example.com
rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
```

If I get http://example.com it redirects to https://example.com. But if I get www.example.com it redirects to https://subdomain.example.com where subdomain is a microsite inside my website.
Any idea what´s the problem when using www?

Comment: Is it cached in your browser? Might want to test in a different browser or using curl.

Comment: No, in diferent devices

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name)

`$server_name` contains the server_name of the virtual host which processed the request, as it was defined in the `nginx` configuration. If a server contains multiple `server_name`s, only the first one will be present in this variable.

`$host` might be the better option in this case it contains "in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the 'Host' request header field, or the server name matching a request"

i.e. something like `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

`$http_host` is also an option as it contains the content of the HTTP "Host" header field, if it was present in the request

[Rewrite vs Return Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites)